# How to add Active Spring Profiles to VSCODE (Spring boot dashboard extension)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, spring-profiles

I am trying to "Debug with profile" my springboot application, in VSCode's Spring Boot Dashboard: Right click on the App -> Debug with profile.
The VSCode shows a popup to Select Active Profiles, but the profile list is empty.
How can I configure the active profiles to be used by VSCode/application, in this case?

[image]

I've tried to find some configuration option in vscode, ctrl + shift + p, etc, without success.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the profile list is filled based on application configuration files that are present under the `src/main/resources` folder. If for example the following files are present:

- application.yaml
- application-dev.yaml
- application-tst.yaml

The `dev` and `tst` profiles will become available in the list.

See also: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-spring-boot-dashboard/pull/309